# How to find the most unique strings in array?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, comparison

I have a lot of strings in array - thousends. I need to compare all strings in that array with each other and find the most unique strings from them.

You can see and test my code, but as you can see - it takes a lot of time (aprox. 160s on localhost = Intel Core i7) to compare just 100 items and I will need to compare thousends... Any ideas how to optimize this code?

I dont need to optimize the first part of code (generating data), because I am extracting data from elsewhere. I just need to optimize second part of code (comparison). As someone noticed, script can be optimized via not doing duplicate comparison (a -> b, b -> a) - I know about this, but still I am trying to save a lot more time than half of it. Maybe there is better function for comparing strings than similiar text, but I dont have experience with something else, thats the reason why I am asking here...

Code:

```
    <?php

    //set how many strings generate for test
    $number_of_test_strings = 100;


    $strings = array();
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $size_chars_array = strlen( $chars );


    /*
     * Creating some random strings - data for test
     */

    //just for testing performance
    $creating_test_data_time_start =  microtime();

    //create some random strings in to array
    for ( $i = 1; $i < $number_of_test_strings; $i++ ) {

        //set random string to empty string
        $random_string = '';

        //choose by random from characters array - also the length of random string will be random - between 1800 and 2500chars
        for( $j = 0; $j < rand ( 1800, 2500); $j++ ) {
                $random_string .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size_chars_array - 1 ) ];
        }

        //insert random string in to strings array
        $strings[] = $random_string;

    }

    //just for testing performance
    $creating_test_data_time_end =  microtime();




    /*
     * Comparison itself
     */


    //just for testing performance
    $uniqueness_time_start =  microtime();

    //foreach for all strings in array
    foreach ($strings as $key_first_element => $first_element) {

        //reset of matched value
        $matched = 0;

        //foreach with each first element
        foreach ($strings as $key_second_element => $second_element) {

            // dont compare the same string
            if ($key_first_element != $key_second_element) {

                //compare those two strings
                similar_text($first_element, $second_element, $match);

                //add match value to matched
                $matched = ($matched + $match);

            }

        }

        // create average uniqueness for that string
        $uniqueness = ($matched / (count($strings) - 1));

        //store it in array
        $uniqueness_array[$key_first_element] = $uniqueness;

    }

    //sort the array by uniqueness (less match the better)- the best on the beginning
    asort($uniqueness_array);

    //just for testing performance
    $uniqueness_time_end =  microtime();


    //just output performance info
    echo 'Creating of test data: '. (array_sum( explode( ' ' , $creating_test_data_time_end ) ) - array_sum( explode( ' ' , $creating_test_data_time_start ) )) .' s, comparing strings: '. (array_sum( explode( ' ' , $uniqueness_time_end ) ) - array_sum( explode( ' ' , $uniqueness_time_start ) )) .' s<br />';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($uniqueness_array as $key_string => $uniquness_of_string)
    {

        // output just 10 best results
        if ($i < 10) {
            echo 'Uniqueness of a string with key '.$key_string.' is '.$uniquness_of_string.'<br />';    
            $i++;
        }
        else break;

    }

    ?>
```

Expected input and output:

```
    //Expected input array
    $input = array(
        'Today is a great day for skiing and I dont have enough time',
        'Wednesday is a very good day for skiing and snowboarding and I dont have enough time',
        'Today is a superior day for skiing and I dont have enough time',
        'Completly different string about nothing'
    );


    //Expected output array - the order is important - the most different strings at the beginning of the array
    $output = array(
        'Completly different string about nothing',
        'Wednesday is a very good day for skiing and snowboarding and I dont have enough time',
        'Today is a superior day for skiing and I dont have enough time',
        'Today is a great day for skiing and I dont have enough time'
    );
```

Comment: What is the idea behind this?  Why must you know the most unique of thousands of different strings?

Comment: most unique ?!? Something is either unique or it isn't unique, there aren't degrees of uniqueness

Comment: So what do you mean by "most unique" at the first place?

Comment: Note that `similar_text` is `O(N^3)`, so for the size and number of strings you are comparing, there may not be any way to improve, unless you can find a faster comparison algorithm, or make less comparisons.  Note also that you are making twice as many comparisons as necessary because you compare `$strings[a]` to `$strings[b]`, and then later compare `$strings[b]` to `$strings[a]`.  However, optimizing this is only going to cut your time in half.

Comment: Another side note for future reference: `for( $j = 0; $j < rand ( 1800, 2500); $j++ ) {` is not an appropriate way to return a random length distribution between `1800` and `2500`, because you are recalculating a new random number with each iteration of the loop.  In fact, as you can see in this example, the average length is more like `1830` instead of the expected `2150`: http://ideone.com/8U9TUd.  You should calculate the limit first, i.e., `$max = rand ( 1800, 2500)`, and then compare `$j < $max`.

Comment: 1. sorry guys for misleading about uniqueness - maybe I should call it - the least matched with others in comparision

2. I know about not comparing twice - but as you noticed, it will cut the time only in half

3. mellamokb, you are right, but I am not generating that strings in my script, they are extracted from database (i put that here, just to have something for testing) - I should wrote that in description, sorry about that

Comment: Unique -> original/rare?

Comment: So, you're looking to count the total number of occurrences of a substring in a larger string? If I have the string "aaba" `a` would have an occurrence of 3 and `b` 1? Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @JohnyBB can you give sample Data of expected input and output ?

Comment: GolezTrol - original is only one, so its not what I am looking for... I have explained it in my previous comment.
TheCapn - I am not trying to find count of the total number of occurences of a substring in a larger string. I am just trying to find the most different strings from others (thats the reason why I used similar_text function and then sorting function in opposite order)

Comment: @Baba - i put expected input and output in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think `similar_text` is enough .. you can combine it with `levenshtein` to get your desired result.

```
$words = array(
    'Today is a great day for skiing and I dont have enough time',
    'Wednesday is a very good day for skiing and snowboarding and I dont have enough time',
    'Today is a superior day for skiing and I dont have enough time',
    'Completly different string about nothing'
);

$unique = array_map(function ($v) use($words) {
    return new Word($words, $v);
}, $words);
```

**Using Similar Text**

```
echo "Uniqness By similar_text\n\n";
usort($unique, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = $a->getSimilar();
    $b = $b->getSimilar();
    return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? - 1 : 1);
});


foreach ( $unique as $var ) {
    printf("%s (%s) \n",$var->getWord(),$var->getSimilar());
}
```

**Similar Text Output**

```
Uniqness By similar_text

Completly different string about nothing (36.363636363636) 
Wednesday is a very good day for skiing and snowboarding and I dont have enough time (75.342465753425) 
Today is a great day for skiing and I dont have enough time (90.909090909091) 
Today is a superior day for skiing and I dont have enough time (90.909090909091)
```

As you can see `Today is a great` and `Today is a superior` are not in the proper position

**Using levenshtein**

```
echo "\n\nUniqness By levenshtein\n\n";
usort($unique, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = $a->getLev();
    $b = $b->getLev();
    return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? 1 : - 1);
});

foreach ( $unique as $var ) {
    printf("%s (%s) \n", $var->getWord(), $var->getLev());
}
```

**levenshtein Output**

```
Uniqness By levenshtein

Completly different string about nothing (63) 
Wednesday is a very good day for skiing and snowboarding and I dont have enough time (63) 
Today is a superior day for skiing and I dont have enough time (45) 
Today is a great day for skiing and I dont have enough time (43)
```

As you can see `Today is a superior` and `Today is a great` both have  very close `levenshtein` distance .. if they end up to be the same the result might not be current

**Combine Both to get Simple Index**

```
echo "\n\nUniqness By Simple Index \n\n";
usort($unique, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = $a->getIndex();
    $b = $b->getIndex();
    return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? - 1 : 1);
});

foreach ( $unique as $var ) {
    printf("%s (%s) \n", $var->getWord(), $var->getIndex());
}
```

**Simple Index Output**

```
Uniqness By Simple Index 

Completly different string about nothing (0.57720057720058) 
Wednesday is a very good day for skiing and snowboarding and I dont have enough time (1.1959121548163) 
Today is a superior day for skiing and I dont have enough time (2.020202020202) 
Today is a great day for skiing and I dont have enough time (2.1141649048626)
```

Combining both gives you a better chance of resolving possible conflicts

**The Class Used**

```
class Word {
    private $lev = 0;
    private $similar = 0;
    private $index = 0;
    private $word;

    function __construct($words, $word) {
        $this->word = $word;
        foreach ( $words as $selected ) {

            if ($selected == $word)
                continue;

            $lev = levenshtein($word, $selected);
            if ($lev > $this->lev)
                $this->lev = $lev;
            similar_text($word, $selected, $match);

            if ($match > $this->similar)
                $this->similar = $match;
        }

        $this->index = $this->similar / $this->lev;
    }

    function getLev() {
        return $this->lev;
    }

    function getSimilar() {
        return $this->similar;
    }

    function getIndex() {
        return $this->index;
    }

    function getWord() {
        return $this->word;
    }
}
```

[SEE LIVE DEMO](http://eval.in/7971)